# Mobile App UX Logo Side Menu Bad Contrast

Tags: bug, design, mobile, accessibility

[image: 310H55V]

The shade of blue used for the menu does not provide a clear contrast with the UXSE logo (need to check WCAG colour contrast requirements). It is probably advisable to review the style guide for designing logos for the Stack Exchange sites, look at using a different colour for the menu UI element or perhaps have different themes (light or dark) for the user interface.

Comment: Just FYI, the development on SE mobile app has been halted/postponed/suspended until no one knows.